# Aztec (DB) Barcode Generator

Tags: c, aztec-barcode

is there an open implementation for an aztec 2D barcode (for the Deutsche Bundesbahn) generator. I do not need the "aztec-data to bitmap", but i need the "input-data to aztec-data" part, the drawing itself is no problem with drawing primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, after long searching I found, that http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/ is capable for that with minor adjustments to the code.

Answer (score 3):

[ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) also supports Aztec encoding since version 2.2.